# After long time of PC being off mysql service doesn 't work

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I Installed MySQL server and MySQL workbench on my PC. Then I restored database. The MySQL is installed on the C drive, Database is located on the D drive. The following problem has occured.

If I shut down PC for 3-5 minutes the MySQL service doesn't work properly. I can not connect to db. I tried to connect with MySQL query, sometimes i connect but then progress stops on the "fetching data" from db. The MySQL service in service manager seems to be running, but if i try to stop/ restart the service it' s stuck on the stopping service...

If I restart PC again then MySQL service work properly and connection is OK, but I need to run MySQL properly after 1st boot not to restart PC after 1st boot after long time.

EDIT:
What I've tried so far:
-reinstall mysql, windows factory reset, create another disk partition for database

Thanks everyone for help (and sorry for mistaken "sql-server" tag.)

Comment: Why did you tag this `sql-server` if you're using MySQL, not Microsoft SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your MySQL server port is free or not ? If not assign different port for your MySQL service to start it.